# Magento update to version 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, composer, guzzle

My current version of Magento is 2.3.2 . I followed the [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)
and i executed the following commands in the console:

```
cp composer.json composer.json.bak
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-updatecomposer require --dev allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.14.0 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 magento/magento-coding-standard:~3.0.0 magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:2.4.5 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 phpmd/phpmd:@stable phpunit/phpunit:~6.5.0 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:~3.4.0 --sort-packages --no-update
composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update

composer update
```

The result of the composer update is the following:

```
  [Composer\DependencyResolver\SolverProblemsException]                                                                                       
  Problem 1                                                                                                                                   
      - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.3].          
      - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3.3 -> no matching package found.                               
    Problem 2                                                                                                                                 
      - magento/framework 102.0.3 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3.3 -> no matching package found.                                             
      - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.3.3 requires magento/framework 102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.3].          
      - Installation request for magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.3.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist-sample-data[100.3.3].  

  Potential causes:                                                                                                                           
   - A typo in the package name                                                                                                               
   - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting                                      
     see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.                                                       
   - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it                                                              

  Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Does anyone know how to fix the this guzzle issue ? Thnx!

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Before starting, make sure you are running PHP 7.1 or 7.2 (recommended).

These are the commands I run:
`composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-update`
`composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update`
`composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update`

Add `"Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"` to `"autoload": "psr-4"` in composer.json if it's not there.

Then run `composer:update` and finish as normal.

Check the vendor folder for guzzlehttp. If that doesn't exist, I'd get a copy of it from the Magento 2 install archive.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses his missing Guzzle package issue

Comment: hmmm I removed the guzzlehttp package from the vendor folder and the composer update was succesfull.  I refreshed the magento page and i received this error message: `Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.` So I run the command, but it seems to be stuck here `Upgrading data...` . I wait 3 hours and it still running :)) . Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Magento root dir, run this command to pull the guzzle package.

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

then go back to your Magento composer installation